# LWC Displaying Table Data using a Custom Class Issue

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Im new to LWC development and am trying to get through an issue Im having. I want to use a custom class list to display a list of data in a data table. The data that Im populating manually (at the moment) is not displaying. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you for your time!

```
onboardingPeople.html

<template>
    <lightning-card title="Handle Error" icon-name="standard:contact">
        <template if:true={error}>
            <p>{error}</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
    <lightning-card title="People"> 
        <lightning-datatable data={people} columns={columns} key-field="accountid"></lightning-datatable>        
    </lightning-card> 
</template>
```

```
onboardingPeople.js

import { LightningElement, wire, track, api} from 'lwc';

import getpeople from '@salesforce/apex/Onboarding.getpeople';

export default class OnboardingPeople extends LightningElement {

    @api people = [];
    @track error;

    @track columns = [
        {
            label: 'First Name',
            fieldName: 'nameUrl',
            type: 'url',
            typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'firstname' }, 
            target: '_blank'},
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Last Name',
            fieldName: 'lastname',
            type: 'text',
            sortable: true
        }

    ];

    @wire(getpeople,{recordId:'$recordId'})
    wiredPeople({error, data}){
        if(data){

            this.people = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {

            this.people = undefined;
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

}
```

```
Onboarding.cls

public with sharing class Onboarding {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<OnboardingPeopleResult> getpeople(String recordId) {

        List<OnboardingPeopleResult> oprList = new List<OnboardingPeopleResult>();

        OnboardingPeopleResult oprobj = new OnboardingPeopleResult();
        oprobj.accountid = '123';
        oprobj.firstname = 'Tom';
        oprobj.lastname = 'Snow';
        oprobj.nameUrl = '/'+oprobj.accountid;

        oprList.add(oprobj); 

        return oprList;
    }
}
```

```
Custom Class

public class OnboardingPeopleResult {

    @AuraEnabled
    public String accountid {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String firstname {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String lastname {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String nameUrl {get;set;} 

    public OnboardingPeopleResult() { 
        this.accountid = '';
        this.firstname = '';
        this.lastname = '';
        this.nameUrl = '';
    }

}
```

[image: Output]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code work ok in my test org when I just added it to a record detail page (though I had to add

```
@api recordId;
```

If you want to use the LWC in a quick action, you should follow the solution [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252191/lwc-as-quickaction-in-salesforce), and wrap it in a aura component - something like this:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
    <c:myonboard recordId="{!v.recordId}></c:myonboard>
<aura:component>
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I added the line of code you recommended but Tom still isn't displaying. As for the Aura Wrapper Im not sure what that is unfortunately. I made my LWC visible to an App Page by setting the Target "lightning__AppPage" in the LWC's meta.xml file. But that is all that I have done for getting the LWC to display on a page. Here's that xml file..

Comment: ```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="OnboardingPeople">
    <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: So if this is on an app page, Tom won't appear because recordId is always NULL. I added the component to an account detail page, and then it worked because recordId is automatically populated to be the current record. Having said that, 
even on an App Page, I don't get the error you are seeing

Comment: How did you add the LWC to a button? It’s not listed in the available lightning components when I go to create the button.

Comment: You mean via a quick action? If so, you'll need to use an aura component that implements quickaction interface

Comment: So just to clarify, I need a Lightning Component to display my LWC? Seems odd but anything's possible with Salesforce. Thank you for the responses its been very helpful.

Comment: Using a quick action would open the LWC in a popup window, correct? If so that will be my next issue. How do I find the URL to my LWC? onboardingPeople.html?

Comment: I updated the answer to use with a quick action - or you can use a URLAddressesable  component and link to that way

Comment: This is great. Thank you for the help!