# Can i add LC button in form?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, create-records, global-actions

I've create custom button in Contact , it's goal is to create custom object record 
I want to add in the form a custom button near Save / cancel which will open another popup ..

**Form**

[image]

is that possible?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the standard quick actions layout of an Object. Consider creating a quick action using an Aura Component/Lightning Web Component.

Build your own form using aura component.
add it to quick action by following these [steps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_component_actions_create.htm&type=5).

You can also use the Lightning web component to build form, but right now LWCs are directly not supported as a quick action, so you will need to wrap that into another Aura component, refer [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252191/lwc-as-quickaction-in-salesforce) question for LWC.

Here are some other references.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_component_actions.htm

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_migration_customization/lex_migration_customization_actions

Comment: What about to build form similair to that form with VF and add the LC button to it ?

Comment: @FirasTaamallah You can use the VF page as well, but why you want to use both VF and LC? I would recommend the Lightning Component.

Comment: VF is easier than LC for me , i'm trying to create new VF page with same fields as form in screenshot , after that i'll add my LC button near Save - cancel buttons , hope it will work

Comment: that will work as well

Comment: How can i use  LC instead of  VF ? should i insert form records with LDS ? i need to add LC button on the form which will open another popup to insert other from records - s that possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. You can use LDS as well. These links might be helpful : [How to Add Lightning Component as a Quick Action in Salesforce](https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/04/16/add-lightning-component-lightning-action/), [Modal/Popup Lightning Component Salesforce](https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/modal-popup-lightning-component-salesforce/)

Comment: But it can not be done , because i should insert records first before calling the button
The goal of the LC button is to add child records so this is canno't be done in  one process , i should first insert form records after that call the button to insert records

Comment: I think you should call it on Save button, wherever parent records are inserted successfully, so no need of another button or disable the button until the parent is not inserted. Do all of this in single component